# Inserting bash positional variable into vim command in a bash file

Tags: vimscript

I have the following in a bash file:

```
prove --merge --normalize -v $1 -a test.tgz
vim -nR -c ':silent 0read ! tar xfO test.tgz $1' -c ':set nonumber' -c ':set syntax=test' -c ':silent !tmux select-pane -L'
```

The problem bit is the `$1` in the second line. The script runs, but it displays the entire archive, not just the file I want: `$1`. If I hardcode the name of file into the script, it works as expected.

And my `tar xfO test.tgz filename` command works find on the command line.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I put in double quotes and it's now working. I swear I tried that before though. Must have had a stray character or something in there before.